# Automatically update blank cells in a range with preceding cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update some blank cell with preceding values in a range of P4 to P22, Q4 to Q22 & R4 t R22. In my case I have values in P4, Q4 & R4 if the cells below are blank and if corresponding column values of X4 matches with the corresponding blank cell values in X5 then the blank cells will automatically get updated. If it doesn't natch then the cells will stay blank. Can some one share a VBA based solution in excel?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time please share code that you have tried so far so it will easier for you and for the one who answering. Here is quick code example I tried to write according to your instructions. It can be improved and adjusted, but it still should do the task required.

```
Sub UpdateCells()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim y As Long

Set sh = Sheets("Your Sheet Name")

For y = 5 To 22 'starting from 5 to 22 since you have asked for this. It can be changed to your liking

    If sh.Cells(y, "X") = sh.Cells(y - 1, "X") Then 'compares values in column X
        sh.Cells(y, "P").Value = sh.Cells(y - 1, "P").Value 'copies values from above if values in column X matches
        sh.Cells(y, "Q").Value = sh.Cells(y - 1, "Q").Value
        sh.Cells(y, "R").Value = sh.Cells(y - 1, "R").Value
    End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer +1. Since you mention improvements: I'd suggest setting up two variables: for the X column and the PQR columns. then the three lines in the if statement become one line. Something like: `data.Rows(y).value = data.Rows(y-1).Value`. Also `i` is a more typical iterator name that `y` (unless you have multiple loops, then it's not uncommon to have x, then y, then z. Or i,j,k), but clearly it makes no difference!

Answer (score 5):

Let me show you, using some screenshots, how I handle this (you can record it into a VBA macro):

Start with a sheet with some data:

[image]

Select the range I want to work with:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> (Goto), and choose "Special". In there, choose "Blanks":

[image]

Start typing a formula in the formula bar (you might need to press <kbd>F2</kbd> for focusing on the formula bar), and type `=B3` (the upper left value):

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl+ENTER</kbd> (don't forget the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button):

Voila:

[image]

Have fun!